# Mediaplayer onError never called

Tags: android, setonerrorlistener

The onError callback is never called. I saw that this is an old bug, is it possibile that it's never been solved?

I've tried to put my emulated device in flight mode while streaming or before buffering, also i've put a button to force a wrong mediaplayer state but none of these tests invoke the onError method.

I've tried with Nougat and Lollipop.

```
public class StreamAudioDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    OnPreparedListener, OnErrorListener, OnCompletionListener {



 MediaPlayer mp;
    Button bt;
    Button bt2;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stream_audio_demo);
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.errore);
        bt.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.i("Stream Audio", "prepare finished");
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.equals(bt)) {
            try {
                mp = new MediaPlayer();
                mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
                mp.setDataSource("http://nr6.newradio.it:9136/stream");
                mp.prepareAsync();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Stream Audio", e.getMessage());
            }
        } else if (v.equals(bt2)) {
            if (mp!=null) {
                mp.prepareAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "ERROR");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

> There is a subtle but important difference between a newly constructed
>   MediaPlayer object and the MediaPlayer object after reset() is called.
>   It is a programming error to invoke methods such as
>   getCurrentPosition(), getDuration(), getVideoHeight(),
>   getVideoWidth(), setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes),
>   setLooping(boolean), setVolume(float, float), pause(), start(),
>   stop(), seekTo(int, int), prepare() or prepareAsync() in the Idle
>   state for both cases. If any of these methods is called right after a
>   MediaPlayer object is constructed, the user supplied callback method
>   OnErrorListener.onError() won't be called by the internal player
>   engine and the object state remains unchanged; but if these methods
>   are called right after reset(), the user supplied callback method
>   OnErrorListener.onError() will be invoked by the internal player
>   engine and the object will be transfered to the Error state.

Following what the reference said i've moved the player creation in the onCreate method and i've put just after the creation mp.reset(), but nothing has changed.

Comment: The onError method from the onErrorListener will only be called during an asynchronous operation. Other errors are raised when the method is called. Possibly your operations are not asynchronous and shall never call the onError method. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html

Comment: prepareAsync() is asynchronous for sure, like also start() i suppose.

Comment: But notice that the documentation on the onErrorListener also says "other errors will throw exceptions at method call time". And if you look at methods like prepareAsync you see that they say they return immidiately and throw an IllegalstateException. The start() works the same way like that. So since they already throw an exception at call time there is no need to also call the onErrorListener, since you can already respond to it properly.

Comment: I see, so It's sufficient a try catch statement.

Comment: Yep :) The OnErrorListener can still be useful in case of streaming services though. It depends on what you want.